# Pressing q does not exit in less running in tmux

Tags: tmux, less

[How to exit file reading mode (in `less`) in Linux terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104502/198423)

> To quit `less`, type `q`.

---

I am using `tmux` on remotely connected node using `ssh`. I am connecting into host as follows: `ssh -xt4C username@host`.

I observe that when I press `q` less does not exit if I am using it under tmux. It just keeps writing `q`. Ex: `lines 62-104/3163 4%qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq`

Is it a normal behavior and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does `:q` work? Or Ctrl-C?

Comment: `Ctrl-c` does not work; `:q` [ENTER] or `q` [ENTER] works

Comment: Does [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253271/understanding-return-enter-and-stty-icrlf) pertain here as regarding `stty -icrnl`?

Comment: Adding `stty icrnl` into `.zshenv` did not solved to problem. But it detects `ctrl-m` as enter, it does not close `less` when I just press `q`

Comment: It seems like tmux doesn't send the command to less unless Enter or Carriage Return signals the end of the line. Does Space work to scroll forward without Enter?